# $f(x)=e^x(x^2-5x+7)$. Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{9^n}\int_{1}^{2}\big((e^x)(x^2-5x+7)\big)^n$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$f(x)=e^x(x^2-5x+7)$$

Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{9^n}\int_{1}^{2}\big((e^x)(x^2-5x+7)\big)^n$

It is supposed to be $0$. I know that $f(x)$ is decreasing over $(1,2)$ from $3e$ to $e^2$. That means when we raise it to any power it will approach $\infty$. So it is an indeterminate form ($\infty/\infty$). Do I apply L'hospital's Rule? How? Maybe distribute the limit? I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Is that $lim_{n \to \infty}$ ?

Comment: @Vizag Yes, I am sorry, edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f'(x)=e^x (x-1)(x-2) < 0$ for $1<x<2$

Hence $\frac{f(x)}{9} \leq \frac{3e}{9}=\alpha <1$ so that $$
\int_1^2 (\frac{f(x)}{9})^n <\alpha^n\rightarrow 0$$

Comment: I love you! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

1. $$\int_{a}^b g(x)dx \leq (b-a)\cdot\max_{x\in[a, b]} g(x)$$
2. if $0\leq a_n\leq b_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=0$, what can you say about $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$?
3. $$|\alpha|<9\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\alpha^n}{9^n}=0$$

Comment: @5xsum This only helps me determine that it is indeed an indeterminate form ($0*\infty$) or ($\frac{\infty}{\infty}$). I do not know how to proceed from there.

Comment: @RaduGabriel Did you even look at the second point (now third point) of my hint?

Comment: @5xsum Of course I did look at your (now-third) hint, no need to be salty. I said I appreciate every and any help, why would I not look at it? All I got from it is that the limit as x approaches infinity of any sub-unitary fraction tends to $0$. Is there more to it? I am sorry if me not getting it is annoying you.

Comment: @RaduGabriel From my first hint, you might notice that the limit you are looking for is bounded above by $\frac{(3e)^n}{9^n}$. You might want to use *all* of the hints I gave. Not just one at a time.